# Magento 2 Checkout billing address validation message

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1.7, validation, messages

I am using Magento 2.1.7

On checkout billing address form, all field has value but if I leave blank first name field validation message is "address is a required field."

I want to change it with specific field name "firstname is a required field."

Comment: i think there is some customization is made other wise default message This is a required field. is appear.

Comment: Yes its need customization but what customization i need to do?>

Comment: You need to create your own custom validation class, to archive this.

Comment: That is right for client side validation but for server side validation class not useful

Comment: Do you get the solution i am currently facing this problem @PrashantValanda